# Getting an error while uploading to s3 `options request denied upload`

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm uploading a file to s3 deep archive through the web dashboard and I get the following error `options request denied upload`.  How do I fix or diagnose?  I am not running an ad blocker, using safari and see no javascript errors in the console.

Comment: Most probably you don't have correct S3 permissions for the user that uploads the file

Comment: how do I configure permissions for the account uploading in the dashboard?  I assume it has some default permissions based on the IAM user associated with the logged in user to the dashboard?

Comment: Take a look at the bucket policy, are there any deny's there?

Comment: no there are not... I used the command line and it seems to work fine, just the online aws dashboard web interface that errors

Answer (score 1):

Try Removing Adblocker if any used in your browser and try to upload it. This surprisingly worked for me!